# Regular expressions working differently

Tags: php, regex

Im testing on this website: [Regex Tester](http://regexpal.com/)

And I came up with this expression `/[\w ]/` that does exactly what I want on that website, which is to select special characters.

BUT when I use it in my PHP file it isnt working.

In my PHP i have this function:

```
function removeSpecialChar($str) {
    return str_replace("/[^\w ]/", "", $str);
}
```

For example lets say that `$str="asdf1234 !"#¤asd"`

It should return `"asdf1234 asd"` but it isnt, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**preg_replace**](http://php.net/preg_replace) when you need the regex-based replacement. [**str_replace**](http://php.net/str_replace) will treat the given string as is - without any special meaning given to metacharacters.

```
$str = 'asdf1234 !\"#¤asd';

function removeSpecialChar($str) {
    return preg_replace('/[^\w ]/', '', $str);
}

echo removeSpecialChar($str); // asdf1234 asd
```

Comment: wow it was the preg_replace, thanks man ive been trying to figure out this for a while now x) I can accept your answer in 7min